# pass where clause condition into a view script in oracle

Tags: sql, parameters, oracle11g, parameter-passing

lets say I create a view like this:

```
    CREATE VIEW LOGICTESTVIEW
    AS
    SELECT /*+ PARALLEL */

    t1.CSCD_NM             
    ,CAST (t1.BTS_ID AS VARCHAR (7)) BTS_ID
    ,trunc(t1.D_DTM, 'DD') D_DTM
    ,sum(t1.V_IVHHO_ATT_CNT) V_IVHHO_ATT_CNT
    ,sum(t1.V_T1_BHL_BLK_CNT) V_T1_BHL_BLK_CNT

    FROM DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI t1

    LEFT OUTER JOIN DMSN.SITES_GEO_HIERARCHY t2
    ON     
    CAST (t1.BTS_ID AS VARCHAR (7)) = t2.BTS_ID
    AND t1.CSCD_NM = t2.CSCD_NM

    LEFT OUTER JOIN DMSN.SITES_SYS_HIERARCHY t3
    ON     
    CAST (t1.BTS_ID AS VARCHAR (7)) = t3.BTS_ID
    AND t1.CSCD_NM = t3.CSCD_NM


    LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT /*+ PARALLEL */
                distinct
                t1.CSCD_NM             
                ,CAST (t1.BTS_ID AS VARCHAR (7)) BTS_ID


                FROM DS3R_FH_EVDO_BTS_LVL_KPI t1

                INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT BTS_ID, CSCD_NM

                        FROM(


                            SELECT /*+ PARALLEL */

                            t1.CSCD_NM             
                            ,CAST (t1.BTS_ID AS VARCHAR (7)) BTS_ID
                            ,trunc(t1.D_DTM, 'DD') D_DTM
                            ,sum(t1.V_IVHHO_ATT_CNT) V_IVHHO_ATT_CNT
                            ,sum(t1.V_T1_BHL_BLK_CNT) V_T1_BHL_BLK_CNT
                            --,sum(t4.BACKHAUL_BLK_CNT) BACKHAUL_BLK_CNT

                            FROM DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI t1

                            LEFT OUTER JOIN DMSN.SITES_GEO_HIERARCHY t2
                            ON     
                            CAST (t1.BTS_ID AS VARCHAR (7)) = t2.BTS_ID
                            AND t1.CSCD_NM = t2.CSCD_NM

                            LEFT OUTER JOIN DMSN.SITES_SYS_HIERARCHY t3
                            ON     
                            CAST (t1.BTS_ID AS VARCHAR (7)) = t3.BTS_ID
                            AND t1.CSCD_NM = t3.CSCD_NM

                            WHERE (trunc(t1.D_DTM, 'DD') BETWEEN to_date('8/28/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('9/3/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy')) AND t2.MRKT_NM = 'East Iowa'

                            GROUP BY 
                            t1.CSCD_NM
                            ,t1.BTS_ID
                            ,trunc(t1.D_DTM, 'DD')

                            HAVING sum(t1.V_IVHHO_ATT_CNT) > 50    

                        )

                        ) t4
                ON
                CAST (T1.BTS_ID AS VARCHAR (7)) = T4.BTS_ID
                AND T1.CSCD_NM = T4.CSCD_NM

                INNER JOIN DMSN.SITES_GEO_HIERARCHY t2
                ON     
                CAST (t1.BTS_ID AS VARCHAR (7)) = t2.BTS_ID
                AND t1.CSCD_NM = t2.CSCD_NM

                WHERE (trunc(t1.D_DTM, 'DD') BETWEEN to_date('8/28/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('9/3/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy')) AND t2.MRKT_NM = 'East Iowa'

                GROUP BY
                t1.CSCD_NM
                ,CAST (t1.BTS_ID AS VARCHAR (7))
                ,trunc(t1.D_DTM, 'DD')

                HAVING
                sum(t1.BACKHAUL_BLK_CNT) > 100
                ) t4
    ON
    CAST (T1.BTS_ID AS VARCHAR (7)) = T4.BTS_ID
    AND T1.CSCD_NM = T4.CSCD_NM

    WHERE (trunc(t1.D_DTM, 'DD') BETWEEN to_date('8/28/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('9/3/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy')) AND t2.MRKT_NM = 'East Iowa' AND t4.CSCD_NM IS NULL

    GROUP BY
    t1.CSCD_NM
    ,t1.BTS_ID
    ,trunc(t1.D_DTM, 'DD')

    HAVING sum(t1.V_IVHHO_ATT_CNT) > 50
```

is it possible to pass what is in the view clause where condition back to the view script instead of hard coding in those where clauses in the view script?

So I query this:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM
    LOGICTESTVIEW
    WHERE (trunc(tD_DTM, 'DD') BETWEEN to_date('8/28/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('9/3/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy')) AND MRKT_NM = 'East Iowa'
```

it would pass the WHERE clause back into those spots in the view script. That way, the user can query their own start and end data, as well as the MRKT name.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible, however you can take a look at `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement, combined with functions/cursors you can get the behavior you want

Comment: just remove the condition from the script and add it to the select from the view as you show.

Comment: OldProgrammer, I'd like to do that, but then it runs each one of those tables across the entire dataset and takes forever